# Load workbook with External Links using openpyxl, is it possible?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Basically I'm using openpyxl to write to existing sheets in this Workbook. The problem is that the load is successful only if I break the DDE link to external data (a software to get real-time quotes). Is openpyxl suitable to this case or do I have to use another python package?
The load error is the following:

```
KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/externalLinks/_rels/externalLink1.xml.rels' in the archive"
```

Btw I'm using openpyxl v3.1.2.